# Creating a Snippet in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am creating a Snippet in Sublime Text 3 however it is not working for some reason. Using the p trigger after saving the snippet gives me the same `<p></p>` as it always does. I have been doing some research but I cannot figure out why. The code is below. It is pretty basic so it is pretty confusing as to why it is not working. Thanks for your help!

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[

<p>
    $1
</p>

]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>p</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Is an error being triggered?  Please define further as what "not working" means.  It will help in determining the solution.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out. It appears in Sublime text 3 you are not able to set a single letter as a tab trigger. I set the tab trigger to lp and it works. If there is a way around this so that I can set it as just p that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to be so vague Steven, thanks for looking into this for me. After saving the snippet using the p trigger simply gives me the <p></p> like it always does. This is what I am trying to change. Thank you.